# Get operating system language in a JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, language-detection

I would like to know if can get the language of a client operating system from a JSP and how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have access to the client's operating system, so your only choice is to rely on the information that is presented to you by the client browser.

The way that the browser presents information about language preferences to the server is by using the HTTP [`Accept-Language`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) header.

Since the information in the `Accept-Language` header can be a little bit hard to parse, in JSP/servlets, you can use the [`ServletRequest.getLocales()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocales()) method, which, according to the JavaDoc

> Returns an `Enumeration` of `Locale` objects indicating, in decreasing
>   order starting with the preferred locale, the locales that are
>   acceptable to the client based on the Accept-Language header. If the
>   client request doesn't provide an Accept-Languag`header, this method
>   returns an`Enumeration`containing one`Locale`, the default locale for
>   the server.